# google search engine inside my drupal / site without show the content to worldwide?

Tags: security, drupal, search, private

i have a site that im developing and i want to put there content and links (some of them are my private home links and stuff) drupal search is good, but its not accurate and also its shows me only things from my site... i want to search all include my website, but dont let google to public it world wide... is taht possible?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to have google index your site without making it accessable to the web. However you can set up a local solr server and user the [Apache Solr Search Integration](http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr) Module to index your site, which is much better than the normal drupal search. That would only provide search for your site still. I'm not sure what you mean by "only shows me things from my site."

If you are not able to host a solr server an alternative is [Acquia's hosted solr search](http://acquia.com/product-matrix). if the pricing is right for you it's a quick and easy way to get solr search on your site.

Comment: is there a way to install it on cpanel sharedhost ? and do i must have tomcat server ?

Comment: installing solr would not be possible using a shared host. Acquia.com offers a "hosted" solr service for as low as $349 per month, which works very well, but may be out of your price range if it's a small site.